# What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, copycat-sites

I noticed a site scraping a Stack Exchange site.

It's quite annoying, as it's obviously occupying server resources and bandwidth that should be available for actual users. There's also no attribution.

What's the policy regarding the reporting of sites like this to administrators?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: You can **report** them to the **respective search engine** if its clone site. They might blacklist it.

Comment: @Nishant: Nope. [They have given up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y/413407#413407) (without really telling us, thus creating a lot of busy work).

Comment: @PeterMortensen reporting them to Google, Bing, DDG etc. is different from reporting them to SE, Inc.

Comment: Chat GPT steals code from Stack Overflow all the time and doesn't provide any attribution.  When anything makes its way to the internet then you can kiss it goodbye.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If the site respects the [attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) and is just a scraper, let it be.

You should [report the site](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), if the site is any of:

- a proxy (i.e., it impersonates or pretends to be Stack Overflow by acting as a middleman);
- is using content copyrighted or trademarked by Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow (e.g., Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange logos, or other content that isn't user contributed); or is
- otherwise actively pretending to be Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange.

Otherwise, if you are not the owner of the content being copied, there is generally nothing you can do and there is no report you need to file. If you are the owner of the content or encountered a proxy, you can read more about available options at [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do)

Even if the site is correctly attributing content, if it is being used to serve Malware, you can also report the site directly to Google using the [spam report tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport).