# Stack Overflow answer copied to forums.asp.net without attribution

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

A comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/2479481) points out [this post on forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/post/4693959.aspx) where the answer body is copied verbatim.

There doesn't appear to be any attribution.

I haven't looked through the forums.asp.net user's other posts to determine if they're making a habit of this.

Does this need to be dealt with?

Comment: The first google hit for that post is also a copy without proper attribution on a vampire site, sevennet.org.  The MSDN post might have been copied from that site :)  Those vampire sites are easier to pursue.  They sure do rank well in the google hits these days.

Comment: Copyright violation has been sanctioned on SO multiple times. Posting full text quotes from SO answers without further additions is nothing more than a corollary of it. If the first is not considered a problem, the latter hardly can't be either.

Comment: I have removed the post from forums.asp.net as it violates the site's terms of use.

Comment: @JensG, pardon? Content is under a quite permissive license, but that doesn't by any means mean that "copyright violation [is] sanctioned".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: [Content has been copied onto SO from other web sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974179/topcoder-flood-relief) which show an [explicit statement](http://www.topcoder.com/community/how-it-works/terms/) about  redistribution of their contents being strictly prohibited, which of course includes SO. The common consensus on SO is: "this is not our problem". But when people start to apply the same logic to SO contents and copy the stuff to somewhere else without permission, it is OK to complain? Sorry, but I can't follow that logic.

Comment: @JensG: A link to meta showing that consensus is needed to make your case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: There is a search function in the upper right corner. If you need a link, add one.

Comment: @JensG, you're the person making as-yet-unsupported assertions about consensus. Burden of proof stands on your side; by contrast, if you're happy to let me go on being (in your view) wrong, I'm happy to proceed as-is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's not much we can do about it. We could always send a DMCA request (heh), but that would require the SE Inc. people to do it.

We could send an email to the MSDN team and ask them to take appropriate action (in this case, adding the necessary attribution), but overall it's a minor thing (in their eyes).

The best we could hope for would be for a MSDN Forums moderator to see this post and take action on their own.

Comment: The author should also be able to file the request too. They still have the copyright on the post.

Comment: @MichaelT That's also true.

Comment: @MichaelT what? You mean that if I make a answer on an SE site its copyrighted?

Comment: @stevebot yes. You are still the copyright holder. Posting on an SE site gives SE a license to publish your answer. There is no transfer of copyright.

Comment: @stevebot: **Everything** is copyrighted as soon as it is "fixed in a tangible medium" (i.e. when you save it to disk, print it, etc.), at least in countries implementing the Berne Convention (nearly all of them).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons why I stopped using Stack Overflow.

(I am the author in question.)

- [My post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/2479481) is dated Jul-2010.
- [The linked article](http://forums.asp.net/post/4693959.aspx) is dated Nov-2011. The
- "MSDN" link refers to forums.asp.net.

Apart from that, my post has several links (including my original source).

Do let me know which of my other answers need attending to...

Comment: You stopped using SO because people really liked your answers and thought them worth copying?  Well, that sucks.

Comment: Please don't stop using SO because of this. The fact that you have great answers means the community as a whole benefits. And you can put your SO reputation on your CV/Resume which will help if you ever switch jobs :)

Comment: Like some other unspeakable things, Stack Overflow reputation points are probably overrated.

Comment: Have you sent a DMCA takedown request, @Christian Payne?

Comment: You don't need to bother with DMCA takedowns or wotnot. Just create an account at the asp.net forums and use the Alert Moderator feature to bring it to our attention.

Comment: Looks like this answer was a reply to [this deleted answer](http://i.imgur.com/eONUoj5.png) posted 3 hours prior to Christian's answer. Please don't blindly downvote this guy.