# 2 scrapers found in the same search

Tags: support, scraping

When doing a following [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ivalueconverter%20%22targettype%20is%20system.object%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for a problem I'm having, I got 4 results.

The top 2 results were to stack overflow questions.
the next 2 results were strangely familiar.  It turns out, they were the exact same 2 stack overflow questions that I had visited earlier.

- [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457158/how-to-convert-back-from-string-to-enum) and [This Question](http://www.dotnetask.com/315_18474046/) are exactly the same.
- [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196937/how-to-create-a-generic-enumconverter-in-windows-universal-app), and [This Question](http://renren.io/questions/4768022/how-to-create-a-generic-enumconverter-in-windows-universal-app) are also exactly the same.

Neither site seems to have made an attempt to link back to stack overflow, but the second question does have links back to stack overflow questions as a result of the OP of the question referencing other answers that were checked.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content, see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers