# How prominent does attribution need to be?

Tags: discussion, attribution, scraping

While looking for an answer to a question I had, using [this Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wpf%20textbox%20multiline%20get%20position), I found:

1. A [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26162701/3160466), right at the top of the results;
2. A [scraped version](http://www.ciiycode.com/0Jmm6PjPQQUX/wpf-multiline-textbox-caret-position.html) of the question *and similar questions list*, about halfway down the results.

The scraped version *does* attribute - but not obviously. Here's the screen you get when visiting the site:

[image: screencap of website]

Only when you scroll right to the bottom, way past all the content, and read the almost-invisible footer, can you find the attribution:

[image: attribution]

**How prominent does attribution need to be to be acceptable?**

(On a quick read of the [Attribution Required blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), it seems this is *not* acceptable, since the question and authors are not linked, but the question stands.)

Comment: Not sure which is worse, the light gray on white color scheme of that footer, or the fact that they put a copyright notice on scraped content.

Comment: More importantly, what can actually be done from a SO perspective to keep this from happening?

Comment: @BrandonB - other than spending lots of money on lawyers to little effect, probably not a lot.

Comment: @BrandonB "Keep it from happening" isn't really completely feasible, not on the internet. However, when SO users find these things, [there are ways to handle them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content), provided they are actually [breaking the license](http://stackexchange.com/legal) that SO has put on subscriber content. Basically, the site has to state the content came from SO, link back to the question on SO, and link to the user's profile for the author of the post.

Comment: Well on the plus side, At least the "Submit Answer!" button at the bottom of the page doesn't appear to actually do anything.

Comment: @ChrisF, you can hire one. How to feed them you might find in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/How-Feed-Lawyer-Observations-Underground/dp/0988391007) :)

Comment: Do we really need to focus on whether the font and color make this attribution count as "clear" when they're blatantly violating the requirements to link to the SO content and author, and also blatantly violating CC-SA?

Comment: @Chris: I understand that SE may not have much investment in spending money on legal attacks against these disgusting scrapers, but personally I feel it would be nice as a high-rep contributor to feel that SE had my back when hooligans in some hut somewhere were making money from ads next to _my_ scraped content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think the answer to this question is really relevant.

From section 3 of [Legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> b. You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
>
> c. You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every question and answer so used.
>
> d. You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection), without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.

Whether or not "This content is from StackOverflow" is clear or not, they've clearly violated the other three terms. There's no link to the question, no mention of the author's name, and no link to the author's profile.

Also, from [CC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/):

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
>
> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.

Again, there's no attribution including a link to the license or an indication of any changes, and the "remixed" content is not licensed under CC-SA.

So, the site is blatantly violating every relevant rule there is, except *maybe* for this one. Does it really matter whether they're also violating this one? Maybe if it comes down to lawyers fighting out the damages, but in that case, leave it up to the lawyers to decide; you don't need to guess.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, as usual, I linked and quoted the "human-friendly" text of CC-SA rather than the "lawyer-friendly" text, because I can actually make sense of the whole thing. But I'm not going to edit it unless someone complains. :)

Comment: While the answer to this particular question could be relevant in other situations, it's also very helpful for future cases that may site this question in deciding to report to have the other three requirements outlined here. You covered the other requirements that are missing from the example site pretty perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question with the information given to us, if you scroll to the footer and click the "[legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal)" link, you'll be taken to the Stack Exchange Terms of Service page.

Section 3 addresses your question, and in the list of requirements, it states (emphasis mine):

> You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. **This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication.**

This tells us that the text *does not* have to be prominent, it just has to be explicitly stated on the page and in a place where it will be able to be found by visitors. (At least, as I understand it. I am not a laywer.) Meaning that the spot that mentions it in your example might comply with this part, though it could at least be an easier color to read the information in. Not everyone is going to be able to read that font size matched with that color, so it could easily be argued as "not clear" in that regard.

Of course, complying with the first of the four requirements doesn't mean the site complies in whole. I would still report them if they are missing the other three using the steps outlined [at Meta Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: Thanks - I've sent a report

Comment: This still leaves the question of whether or not the attribution on that site is "clear" or not.

Comment: @Servy Which I think will end up being a personal thing in this case, given the colors they use. Clear in message, I would say for sure. Clear to read.... Well, I personally find it clear, even in the OP's non-zoomed in image. But I can see how others would not find that coloration clear. If all the other attribution requirements were met, which the OP says are not, I would consider sending this one in anyway as I'm sure there are a good number of people that would not be able to read that color/font size.

Comment: @Servy: Who cares? "You've violated the CC-SA license, and also violated 3 of the 4 SE-specific terms of use, and may or may not have violated the 4th" is surely as good as "You've violated the CC-SA license, and also violated 4 of the 4 SE-specific terms of use". If it comes down to lawyers negotiating, the lawyers will just turn that "may or may not" into "definitely" and they can argue from there.

Comment: @abarnert But that's not what the question is asking about.  Yes, it's clear that several pieces of attribution are missing, meaning this site is in violation, but the quesiton isn't asking if this site is in violation of the licence, it's asking how visible the attribution needs to be, so discussions about whether the attribution that was given is sufficient visible is something that you *should* care about when discussing this question, if not, then apparently you don't care about *the entire question*.

Comment: @Servy: Now that I think about it, I actually _don't_ care about the question exactly as written, because I just don't believe there are going to be many cases where some site does everything else right, but it's borderline on whether their "content from StackOverflow" counts as visible enough. And, if there _is_ such a case, I don't think anyone would actually care enough to raise it, and I don't think SO would do much if you did raise it. It's not just that this case is an artificially-constrained issue; virtually all similar cases will be.