# Is StackTheOverflow a real StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, copycat-sites

Today I was googling for the answer to a programming question and as usual there were a list of StackOverflow answers that came up. However, this time there was also a link to a question on www.stack**the**overflow.com. Here is the link:

http://www.stacktheoverflow.com/questions/20592747/horizontal-scroll-view-detect-long-press

It looks exactly like StackOverflow and the only reason I noticed that anything was different is that I wasn't logged in anymore. I googled "stacktheoverflow vs stackoverflow" and didn't see anything. I searched on StackOverflow meta for "stacktheoverflow" and also didn't see anything.

I thought at first that it might be a phishing site but why does it come up so high in Google's results? What is this site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content). Also see [Updated procedure for reporting
SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: Thanks, @CoolGuy. I wasn't aware of that term. I'll report it.