# What is stacktheoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, scraping

Recently I was looking for tips on how to do some programming things, so I used Google to help aid in my search. Several Stack Overflow questions appeared as a result of my input query, but as I scrolled down the Google page, I saw a link to a site whose web address was http://www.stacktheoverflow.com.

I was somewhat suspicious of this site and decided to check it out. What I found was that pretty much *everything* was a complete copy of Stack Overflow.

Most of the places I tried to access either resulted in a "500 Internal Error" message (or something of the like) appearing, or a lot of the web pages failing to load completely.

I don't know if this is an actual scraper site or if there's something I'm missing, but if it's the former then we may have to keep an eye on it and/or report it.

Comment: There was [a question about this exact site 2 days ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293698/is-stacktheoverflow-a-real-stackexchange-site), but I voted to close as a dup of the general question it's a specific instance of.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293698/62576

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I wasn't aware of that question.