# Too many [copycat-sites]. Time for faq?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

If you look at the questions for [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites), a lot of them are duplicates.  The most common target for the duplicates is [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content).  Is it time to make a single, canonical [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?  IMO, the number of copycat sites will only grow, and people will continue to ask how to report them.

Potential options I see:

- Convert the [duplicate target mentioned above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content) to a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (after some editing).
- Create a new [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) question and answer.
- Leave things the way they are and continue to enumerate new copycat sites with separate questions.  Then duplicate close them.
- Edit the [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) tag description itself to try to proactively ward off duplicates and deal with whatever falls through.

There is also the separate issue of whether we need to publicly catalog these sites.  If so, would a single community wiki (such as the faq) be a better place to consolidate these sites, or should each site have its own question listing?  There are also lots of resource on MSE, but what should we do for MSO?

Comment: Do you really think it'll reduce the number of questions asked by more than just a few to make the question an FAQ?

Comment: Yes (if we edit the copycat-site tag).  Also, how important is cataloging the copies?  If it is important, I think the faq still makes sense.

Comment: Why do they need a public catelogue? The process asks that you contact SE. People keep asking the question and these keep getting closed as a dupe of the one that enumerates the process...

Comment: @Ben that's actually part of my question.  So I guess your answer to that one is "No, they don't need cataloging"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have edited the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/copycat-sites/info) for [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) to be more informative.

[Stack Exchange does not want us to be maintaining these lists anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers), they want us to report them using the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link:

> **Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the form on the [*contact us*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) page, linked at the bottom of every page.**
>
> Use the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" reason on the form. Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

Hopefully the tag wiki improvement should be enough to address your concerns.

Comment: The tag still does not show a link to the contact us location, you need to click the "?" icon, which most people don't click.