# I reported a copycat site / content farm and was responded with "this may help you recover your password"

Tags: support, copycat-sites

I reported a website that scrapes content off of the Stack Exchange network using the /contact page with the following input:

> *Date:* 11/28/2021 12:00:00 AM
>
> *Link to scraper:* [redacted]
>
> *Link to our content:* [redacted]
>
> *Search terms:* makefile quoting
>
> - *Submitted email:* [redacted]
> - *Topic:* Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution
> - *Logged in user:* https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug
> - *Browser:* [redacted]
> - *IP Address:* [redacted]
> - *Request URL:* https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact/submit
> - *Referrer:* [Too many [copycat-sites]. Time for faq?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297840/too-many-copycat-sites-time-for-faq)

A few hours later, I got a response that I couldn't understand in this context:

> Hello,
>
> This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reset-password) may help
> you recover your password.
>
> Thanks,
> The Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange support teams
>
> ______________________________
> Your Ticket ID: [redacted]
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Team

Is there any magical link between resetting my password and a copycat site?

Comment: No, but [so] don't take reports for scraping/copycat sites any more [unless it's a proxy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do/200178#200178). The owner of the content (the question/answer) needs to contact the site instead.

Comment: @Larnu Then the tag wiki for [meta-tag:copycat-sites] needs an update.

Comment: Indeed it does, @iBug . I, personally, would have preferred it if SO had been better at communicating their change in stance; the only way to find out was if you happened to revisit the linked Answer.

Comment: Well, certainly I was misled by the tag wiki for \[copycat-sites\] [at the time](/revisions/272273/4). I've updated it just now and I can sympathize with how they have to choose a boilerplate response with something they don't want to handle.

Comment: In fairness, their reasoning is somewhat sound. The majority of content on the sites doesn't belong to Stack Overflow, it belongs to whomever contributed it, and SO can't make a licence infringement notification to 3rd parties on behalf of content they don't own; especially if the owner themselves hasn't asked them to do so.

Comment: "*Is there any magical link [...]*" considering that "I lost my password" is the first valid option on Contact Us, it might be the default fallback...

Comment: I wouldn't like to comment, @IanKemp . I, at least, know that previously when I reported sites that duplicated the work that they did tend to get removed (though sometimes months later). I won't deny, however, that it annoys me that people are making money off of someone else's work without attributing the original author. Plagiarism is a something I really hate.

Comment: *"No, but Stack Overflow don't take reports for scraping/copycat sites any more unless it's a proxy."* - That is utter garbage... the fact that it's true is quite upsetting.

Comment: My guess is that since they don't take reports for scraping/copycat sites any more, they probably deleted the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" server-side but forgot to delete it client-side, which would cause the server not to recognize the topic and fallback to "I lost my password". I don't know what their code actually looks like though, so a staff member would have to confirm whether or not this is the case.

Comment: @Larnu [It wasn't us causing them to disappear.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343405/141525)

Comment: But what about the satisfaction that comes from sending Stacksassins? How can you enjoy life without crushing your enemies, seeing them driven before you, and hearing the lamentations of their significant others?

Comment: @animuson: Of course it wasn't you -- it obviously was the reporters recovering their passwords that caused the copycat sites to disappear.

Comment: To me, one of the most annoying ones is this 'codegrepper.com' site. Blatant scraping, with no real value. It pollutes the search results. I've taken to putting " -codegrepper" at the end of my searches but it doesn't always work. Not sure why.

Comment: @McAuley Try a browser extension called *uBlacklist*. Find a decent ruleset on GitHub and you're good to go (like me).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no connection to them, and it was just a mistake of the person who responded sending the wrong message along when replying. Wouldn't be a new support person if you don't end up sending the wrong message to someone eventually... I've certainly done it plenty of times in the past.

For those interested, this is the usual canned message that gets sent along to all scraper reports now, and the one you should have received:

> All content on Stack Exchange is licensed under either CC-BY-SA 3.0 or CC-BY-SA-4.0. The Creative Commons licenses permit other sites to reproduce content that appears on the Stack Exchange network, so long as they follow the Creative Commons attribution requirements.
>
> Because we have no standing to ask another site to take down content they have reproduced from our site, there is unfortunately very little we can do to address scrapers, and we are no longer pursuing these avenues as a company.
>
> Thank you for your diligence. The attention paid by users like you keeps Stack Exchange a functional and durable community resource.
>
> Please write back if you have any further questions.

Comment: Yup. The new reply I got opened with *We want to apologize for the confusion, the previous answer was not meant to be sent to you, so you know there is a human behind this email and not a machine.*

Comment: All content on Stack Exchange is licensed under either CC-BY-SA 3.0 or CC-BY-SA-4.0 or CC-BY-SA 2.5 (in a few cases still probably).

Comment: That is disappointing. Could [another](https://www.linux.com/news/gpl-passes-acid-test-german-court/) [organisation](https://gpl-violations.org/news/20060922-dlink-judgement_frankfurt/) do it? Perhaps add some information about this to the answer?

Comment: Couldn't Stack Exchange use [Database right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_right) to prevent such copycat sites, at least in countries that understand it legally? If I understand it correctly, only the individual contributions (= every post on its own) is licensed under CC-BY-SA. Is Stack Exchange required to license the full database on its own under CC-BY-SA?

Comment: So, if they don't follow attribution requirements, can you sue?