# Cannot submit "merge user profiles" option in Contact Us form

Tags: bug, status-completed, contact-form

I am trying to create a merge account request via https://stackoverflow.com/contact but it seems not to work. When filling the form, I am getting a message that the merge request cannot be submitted until I enter both account URLs. Adding the URLs to the description doesn't work. I've inspected the HTML of the form and found that there are elements, more precisely, input fields with IDs "profileLink" and "otherProfileLink" which are not visible despite selecting "I need to merge user profiles" in the drop down menu. Question: Does anyone else have this problem too? How can I make the two inputs visible to proceed with my merge request?

[image: Merge request]

Comment: Doesn't appear to be browser specific. I can repro the boxes not appearing in both Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 and {shivers} Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [the form was still working last week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413386/2821954), but I just tested on other SE sites and they also didn't work. One of the most recent network-wide changes that I could only notice.... is [the JavaScript migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/241919).

Comment: I also tested on Edge and Firefox. Both not working

Comment: Not working in chrome (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: For now you can try opening the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and entering this: `document.querySelectorAll(".js-profile-url-block, .js-other-profile-url-block").forEach(({ classList }) => classList.remove("d-none"));`, then hitting `Enter`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon with JS migration(possibly), SO wants all of SE users to be web devs ;P

Comment: This is a bug related to the JavaScript migration, I'm working on a fix now.

Comment: The bug has come back: I have been trying since about last month, April 2023, to fill the merge form, with the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug related to our [migration to modules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript).   This impacted the contact form across all network sites. The contact form wasn't being initialized correctly so the support topic selector wasn't showing the right form fields. However, the form validation was still working correctly which prevented the form from submitting.

A fix went out earlier today and the form should now be working again.