# How does Stack Exchange react when licenses are violated?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing

See for example howtofix.io.

https://howtofix.io/pattern-matching-in-postgres-select-query-id1631481

Clearly this website is using content created by the SO contributors, which are licensed under CC BY-SA as stated at the bottom of the SO website "site design / logo © 2022 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa. rev 2022.1.26.41266 "

Hence I'd expect to see at least the names of the contributors, and a link to their SO profiles.

There is a link to the SO question so I guess SO itself is not being blurred. However, suppose SO disappears for some reason, then all of its users' content suddenly belongs to an unknown website, with no license attached.

My guess is that it's the role of the users to react. On the other hand, they would probably appreciate if SO takes the initiative to speak for them in this kind of situation.

Is there any kind of related legal precedent?

Comment: See [What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?](/q/253906/4642212).

Comment: Nowadays, SE.Inc will do nothing. They don't pursue these matters any more.

Comment: @VLAZ We *never* actually pursued them. We tracked them out of interest for a while, and reported those that outranked us to Google before they shut down that form. And long, long ago we occasionally sent vaguely worded requests that never received replies. But the fact that there isn't anything we can legally do has never changed.

Comment: The advice used to be to report sites that violate the license to SE. I was not aware there has been basically no action for my reports.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I followed the advice at the bottom of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178 and sent a violation report to GoogleAds.

Comment: @VLAZ: That was a surprise for most us, I think. See for instance [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413407) from December 2021 (*"Because we have no standing to ask another site to take down content they have reproduced from our site, there is unfortunately very little we can do to address scrapers, and* ***we are no longer pursuing these avenues as a company."*** (My emphasis.)).

Comment: Yeah it seems like it just isn't something you can keep up. You either have an expensive legal department full of bloodhounds or you probably just want to look the other way.