# Any recourse for answers put in commercial publication without credit?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, licensing

Several weeks ago I was reading through a commercial publication (a book) on a niche platform and noticed it contained, verbatim, a long form answer I posted to a question on Stack Overflow. Skimming through the rest of the book I identified code that was copied from two  different Stack Overflow answers (both of which I posted in 2017).

Is there any recourse through Stack Overflow? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) and since I was not given credit it violates the license agreement. I know the book's author's Stack Overflow account. Is there any procedure for handling a situation where a **known** Stack  Overflow user plagiarizes your content?

Comment: Possibly related: [Are these eBooks that copy from SE illegal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273989/241919). Otherwise, for no proper attribution: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. I looked at the post just now.  Not sure if its relevant, but I saw the plagiarism when I was skimming through a physical book in Barnes & Noble.  I guess the answer is in your second link, and its report the plagiarism here https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: Ah, I see, it's a physical book. However, while the situation is different (online vs offline), the second link may help to understand that SE cannot do anything since they're not copyright holders; you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: @AndrewT. your second link was helpful - there is a standard way to report reproduction without attrition.  I will at least do that and send the authors username. Ty.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli There's little point in doing that. As Andrew said, there is nothing we can do and we do not process scraper reports in any way. Contacting us hoping something will change will do nothing. You'll need to plan your own strategy depending on how much you care about it having been published without attribution.

Comment: @animuson ok thanks for the response.  My $0.02 is that if plagiarism can be linked back to a specific user ( the plagiarizer ) there should be some type of in-app disincentive.  Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli You seem to still be of the belief that SE should take care of this for you. It's not just that SE chooses not to, it's that they legally *CANNOT* do anything, because they are not the copyright holder, so have no standing to do anything in court, and court action is the *only* real recourse. *YOU*, the copyright owner, or your agent/lawyer, are the *only* ones which have standing in court to actually do something about the copyright violation which you've described above.

Comment: Side issue: your description in the question makes it sound like you copied substantial content from somewhere else into your question, but changed the screenshots. Please [edit] to clarify if that's what you did, or not.

Comment: @Makyen I removed the entire paragraph because it added nothing to the post

Comment: So basically we would need a second complimentary entity to SE, maybe something like a content contributor association, that could on behalf of its members  take action on such stuff.

Comment: @Trilarion I was thinking just temporarily suspend the users who plagiarized your work ( assuming they are a member, and you can prove it was that user who did it, which is the case in this circumstance ).  I don't expect SO to take any action outside of SO

Comment: @Makyen OP is not asking for SO to fix this legal/copyright problem for them. They're asking whether the copying user could be penalized. Say there is a user who goes by the same username as the book author, whether you can do anything about that, like send them a stern warning about plagiarism, just like your can ban people copying answers on-site.

Comment: I don't have any experience with trying to engage the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/pages/legal-assistance) in this sort of issue, but I believe they have in the past taken up _pro bono_ cases where individual copyright holders with limited resources were up against corporations with more or less deep pockets. My impression is that they might very well be interested in litigating on your behalf, or at the very least to hear you out. (Assuming you and the publisher are both in the United States; if not, you are probably effectively out of luck.)

Comment: @tripleee: [An example is](https://www.linux.com/news/gpl-passes-acid-test-german-court/) [the D-Link (router) case](https://gpl-violations.org/news/20060922-dlink-judgement_frankfurt/).

Comment: Just write to the publisher of that book and tell him that there has been used unauthorized material from you and that you are not agreeing to this. The answer will be telling.

Comment: There isn't [any real protection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y/413407#413407), unless some third party is willing to do it.

Comment: Another approach would be to contact the publisher. They may well have incentives to compensate you.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's still a question about law, which is off topic here. [law.se] might be able to help, but the indicated course of action is still to talk to a real lawyer in real life. It is unreasonable to expect SE to intervene with verbal sanctions for something that might actually be illegal and also hasn't been tested in a court of law. Among other things, I can imagine this opening them up to liability for libel. (I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.)

Comment: @Karl no, asking about Stack Overflow's policies is never offtopic on meta, regardless of the topic. The answer can be "We won't do anything", but that doesn't make the question off-topic. I am not saying that SO _should_ be judging and taking action here, I'm just pointing out that that is what the question here is about, which some people seem to be missing. Nobody is asking what SO the company could legally do in this situation; that's a whole nother question. OP is just asking whether there is any process in place for this situation, and the answer appears to be "no".

Comment: I agree that SO is not the right party to take action againt plagiarism done outside of SO (that is, the real world). Otherwise it would be to SO's discretion to decide what is copyright infringement and what isn't which brings up another issue where opinions might affect the result which should be done purely based on facts and the law.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I find your point preposterous.  If someone came into SO and made a direct threat against someone in the comments ( possibly doxxing, etc ) it would be SOs obligation to remove that person from the platform. Now, in that case there is an additional legal component as well. However, I think it’s been made clear that this topic isn’t a legal discussion. It is a discussion about an active SO user violating the rules set out by SO. The question is essentially “If someone breaks a SO rule ( see licensing ) are they held accountable?”

Comment: The problem with that is that the violation took place outside of SO, so there is nothing for to sanction for Stack Exchange. You are the copyright holder, and defending your copyright is your responsibility. Taking moderation action like temporarily suspending a user for things happening outside of Stack Exchange would be a very slippery slope.

Comment: If the book is also published online and you can contact the publisher, one of the first steps I'd take is to file a DMCA takedown notice. There are plenty of templates for it and the DMCA is applicable in that case. For physical copies, however, it isn't, but it may draw enough attention to open a conversation about licensing the plagiarized material, and it's much easier than filing an ordinary copyright claim.

Comment: @animuson Are you saying that Stack Exchange won't penalise or warn user X in any way if user X blatantly plagiarises the work of user Y but has user Y's material published off-site? Even if it's obvious that the off-site author is user X (eg, because they use their real name)? Of course, I don't expect SE to get involved in copyright litigation.

Comment: @Makyen If a user holds the copyright then they should be able to freely delete any post they've made on SO. Since this isn't the case, SO must hold the copyright. Or if they don't, they must have created a very questionable EULA which goes against national copyright laws... And no matter who owns the copyright, SO is the responsible publisher. Lets say I work as freelance journalist for a newspaper. The article in the newspaper then gets plagiarised in a competing newspaper. How can it be the freelancer's responsibility to bring the other newspaper to court? It's not their loss of profit.

Comment: @Lundin No, your understanding of copyright law and contracts (in this case, licenses) is incorrect. If you buy a physical book which the copyright owner validly authorized to be created and distributed, then the copyright owner doesn't have the right to come into your home and take the book back. Users don't have a *right* to delete their content, because by posting they licensed the content to Stack Exchange under the CC BY-SA license (at least; some versions of the TOS have had an additional license), which is irrevocable, due to the text in the contracts (licenses, TOS).

Comment: Your example of the freelancer and paper isn't valid, because there *will be* different contracts involved, probably resulting in a completely different relationship between the original paper and the freelancer. For copyright, there's a baseline set of rules which are the laws, but then the situation can be *dramatically* altered by contracts between parties, including the ability to transfer the copyright. Copyright *law* deals primarily with the situation between the copyright owner and parties with whom the owner has not made any agreements. Past that, it's into *widely* varying contracts.

Comment: The publisher might have a page explaining how you can report copyright violations by their authors.  O'Reilly's is here: https://www.oreilly.com/about/copyright.html.

Comment: SE doesn't care: [Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342516/178179)

Answer (score 21):

I agree with many comments, in particular those of Mark Rotteveel and tripleee.

No, there should not be a recourse through Stack Overflow, because the infringement occurred outside of Stack Overflow. There wouldn't have occured anything directly sanctionable on this exchange. You are the copyright holder and it's your responsibility to assert your copyright. Any moderator action like for example a temporary suspension of a user for issues outside of this platform would be a very slippery slope indeed.

However, if you want to do something about it personally, you can for example write to the publisher of that book and tell him that there has been used unauthorized material from you and that you are not agreeing to this. The answer will be telling. They might even be willing to financially compensate you in exchange for your approval.

At the very least they may add the required attribution (in later/electronic versions) and be more careful. If you are not satisfied, you could even try to contact the Electronic Frontier Foundation about this. They are known to have taken up pro bono cases in order to defend copyright of individuals against big corporations.

See also the "What actions can I take myself?" section of the [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/260073) of [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do).

Comment: Just some comment on formatting: While it's true that quote blocks are made for larger amounts of quotations, quotation marks " are also made for this and look better here in my opinion, because they do not disrupt the sentences so much. I can read it better that way.

Comment: ``the violation took place outside of SO``.  Is it though? The "violation"  here requires two actions - copy and paste. The first action requires accessing content from SO. The infringement would not have occurred, if content was not accessed from SO first. I would argue the violation started here first and is completed elsewhere. If users contribute to SO  and SO benefits from these voluntary contributions, SO has a obligation to protect these users and their contributions from plagiarizing users.

Comment: There's no equal penalty to apply. @TheMaster. Their "infraction" was publishing it without attribution, elsewhere. No penalty here can prevent that.

Comment: @TheMaster neither copying nor pasting is a violation though (thank goodness). The actual action which caused the violation was publishing.

Comment: @Shadow  The violation is impossible to accomplish without accessing SO first. SO provided access to the content, benefits from the licence, and therefore has a obligation to penalize plagiarism. It already penalises plagiarism. The place of violation occurring elsewhere is not a valid  justification, because to accomplish the said violation, access is provided here.

Comment: @TheMaster SO could be seen as helper or facilitator here, but again it's a slippery slope. What comes next? Suing SO for providing Russian missile makers with technical knowledge, or gun makers for what bad things guns in general can do... the possibilities are endless. Where do you want to draw the line?

Comment: @Trilarion I want to draw the line at SO ToS and the already existing policy. Plagiarism is already penalized by SO. I don't see the place of violation exception as valid justification. Two users  both agreed to SO terms. One user plagiarised another user of the content that was posted and licensed to SO. SO should intervene. It is logical and rational.

Comment: @TheMaster It may be helpful to put it in an answer, so people can vote on it and if it garners enough votes maybe the company will take notice and do what you want it to do.

Comment: @TheMaster That's like saying "it would have been impossible for the thieves to steal your car if you didn't buy one". It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Shadow If all you care about is minimizing stealing of cars, then not buying any cars is one possible logical and rational answer. But the suggestion of TheMaster is more like, deny him public transport as punishment, after all he might have a car too much. The whole thing may require some sort of balancing of different interests in the end.