# What can I do when I found a website plagiarized content from SO without attribution?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I stumbled across [this link](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/1-34-pm-margaret-maher-python-exception-error-bad-magic-000025627#:%7E:text=Description&text=The%20%22magic%20number%22%20comes%20from,correct%20when%20loading%20the%20file.) when I was trying to find a solution to a problem I had about *magic number error*. I read it, and then decided I needed more information, so I continued my research and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/514395/3701393) in SO.

*Wait a second. It has almost the same writing.*

So, I checked which one was created first. It was the one in SO. The other one was created recently without any attribution whatsoever.

Here comes the question. What can I do when I found a website plagiarized content from SO without attribution? Or should I even do anything about it?

***Note: I am not related to neither sides.***

Comment: *"Note: I am not related to neither sides."* - Double negative, so you are related to at least one side ;) At least once a month there is a post that essentially is meant so we pull out the torches and pitchforks, scraping sites just pop up like mushrooms now. Besides, we're in the wake of the most heinous scrape of all times; the one OpenAI did. I'm kind of numb to it now to be honest. Do not care, scraping is normal.

Comment: Just for a counterpoint, I care. The license terms should be enforced where possible and practical. Note that particular content dates from 2009 and may be under a different license that I no longer remember. The linked answer suggests that only user paxdiablo can do anything about this.

Comment: One thing that I like to do is scan SO for any references to the host using the `url:` search and replace them. E.g. `url:appsloveworld` is one of the worst. I think it used to be partially a legit blog but now is just a scraping site.

Comment: It is [futile to report it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274625/does-stack-exchange-take-any-measures-against-sites-violating-our-license#comment1286842_274625) (busy work). [They gave up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y/413407#413407) a long time ago.

Comment: There are many things we could do, but few of them that are both legal and satisfying.