# Is this "copy site" affiliated with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

I'm familiar with [what I should do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content) when encountering a "[clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)" site, but I hesitate to report [this one](http://stackoverflow.link/) as I'm uncertain as to whether or not it is affiliated with the actual SO site.

The fact that they use "Stack Overflow" as the headline of the site, with the url `http://stackoverflow.link/`, both of which are in clear violation of the guidelines documented [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (Thanks @BoltClock) has me scratching my head.

Would a copy site really have the intestinal fortitude to rip off the site name/URL?
How should I proceed?
Should I report this or forget about it?

I see a site that says "Stack Overflow" all over the place and want to make sure that it isn't related to Stack Overflow before I say, "Hey, SO. Check our your own site! It's copying your own site!"

Comment: What about that site would have given you the impression that there's any kind of affiliation at all?

Comment: I see a site that says "Stack Overflow" all over the place and want to make sure that it isn't related to StackOverflow before I say, "Hey, SO. Check our your own site! Its copying your own site!" Its as simple as that.

Comment: No really, there's nothing on that site that has or uses any of the official or recognized Stack Exchange branding. It's *just* the name.  There's nothing there that would even remotely indicate affiliation.

Comment: @Makoto: Pretty sure the title is a trademark, though. In fact, the domain is quite categorically a [trademark infringement](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: @BoltClock:  When I said "branding" I had meant/implied something that would identify it as an official Stack Exchange site.  Things like the logo would be something you'd expect to see on any Stack Exchange site, or Stack Overflow.  Merely mentioning the name isn't *exactly* the same as using the uniquely identifiable brand images.  I wholeheartedly agree that the domain name is a trademark violation, though.  I'm no lawyer so I can't say much further than this, but the copycat site doesn't have anything outside of the words "Stack Overflow" to indicate its affiliation.

Comment: @That1Guy If I made a site looking the same but saying Apple instead of Stack Overflow in the top right would you believe the sight is affiliated with Apple?

Comment: @idmean: [Yes.](http://wbj.pl/apple-to-sue-polish-firm)

Comment: They're displaying Google ads, so I found a page displaying one of my questions and [reported it to Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/violation_report) as a violation of their content policy and my copyright as I own the copyright to the question and they violated the attribution requirements. Maybe if enough people do this, Google will disable their ads account, and they'll shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a whois on that url and this is the result:

> Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.INFO
>   Domain ID: D54673942-LRMS
>   WHOIS Server:
>   Referral URL: http://www.wildwestdomains.com
>   Updated Date: 2015-05-08T20:30:23Z
>   Creation Date: 2015-03-09T10:08:05Z
>   Registry Expiry Date: 2016-03-09T10:08:05Z
>   Sponsoring Registrar: Wild West Domains, LLC
>   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 440
>   Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
>   Registrant ID: CR189640730
>   Registrant Name: Stephen Bond
>   Registrant Organization:
>   Registrant Street: 92 Hilliard Rd
>   Registrant City: Chichester
>   Registrant State/Province: New Hampshire
>   Registrant Postal Code: 03258
>   Registrant Country: US
>   Registrant Phone: +1.6037983917
>   Registrant Phone Ext:
>   Registrant Fax:
>   Registrant Fax Ext:
>   Registrant Email: svede001@yahoo.com
>   Admin ID: CR189640731

You can compare that with the whois from stackexchange.com to learn that we don't have a site here that is owned by Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow (the company).

As the site reportedly showed google ads that is a second give-away that something strange might be going on, as Stack Exchange run their own ads.

Given that evidence I think it is enough to err on the save side and report the site so the people that are familiar with the exact legal rules and procedures can take the steps needs.

As an additional effort you can follow the advice given by [Joshua Dwire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1721527/joshua-dwire) and report the site to Google as well.