# Why we are all (or the most of us) on troublevn.com

Tags: discussion, support

I'm sorry I don't know where to post this, but I was a little confused, that I saw my [profile](http://troublevn.com/user/swidmann) on troublevn.com.

Here is a [link](http://troublevn.com/users) to the current user list.

As I saw after some googling:

> The site is hosted in Russian Federation by Ltd Kominvest.

I thought, well I don't think this is a page from the SO Network.
So is there anything we can do against this?

PS: If this question is wrong here, please move it to the right place. Thanks a lot

Comment: 'Why we are all on troublevn.com' .... I'm not on there. Maybe I'm not cool enough.

Comment: @MacroMan :), ok I guess **all** was bit too much

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content#answer-253908

Comment: @MacroMan, thanks this answered my question, I think it does not respect the attribution requirements, so I'll get in contact with SO