# What is stackoverflow.xyz?

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

Today I searched for websites linking to my website and my Stack Overflow profile are one of the pages linking to it. Then when I looked a bit further down, I found another website linking to my page. So I saw that it was an exact copy of [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) and it is called [stackoverflow.xyz](http://stackoverflow.xyz/). Is this one of Stack Exchange's sites? Should I report it?

**Note**: I looked at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content), but it seems to be about sites that has some posts or a post of the Stack Overflow, not an exact copy of the Stack Overflow.