# Do Real Programmers Copy/ Paste Code From Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I saw this video on youtube and was wondering if this site has problems with plagiarizing this site's content.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBi3S97R60k

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/314988)"

Comment: Accusing such programmers of plagiarism is like saying that Beethoven plagiarized Bach because he used the same musical notes.  Snippets are *meant* to be copied, they solve small problems.  Programmers that *only* copy snippets and never write their own code and still produce a working useful program have a very unusual talent.  Nobody can do that.  It is only ever plagiarism when you republish the snippet for others to see and pretend that you wrote it.

Comment: To be fair, the video does say copy/paste/modify. That last bit is kind of important.

Comment: http://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow

Comment: Didn't a major car manufacturer fire one of it's developers for doing this the other week?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do Real Programmers Copy/ Paste Code From Stack Overflow?

Yes, they do. I'm not sure what you mean by "Real programmers" though..

> if this site has problems with plagiarizing this site's content.

Sure it does. Many people who use code from SO (And other websites which scrape / republish content from SO) don't bother attributing the user who wrote / posted that code, as is required by the license (CC-BY-SA). Unfortunately, there's nothing much you can do about that. However, If there's another website using content from SO, see [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content).

Comment: Thank You. I'm new to this site and was just wondering how things like that work here.

Comment: [Real Programmers are the ones using butterflies to code.](https://xkcd.com/378/)