# Are we aware of Stackfullow and what can we do to stop it?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Via a search engine I found a result on what seemed to be SO. Clicking the link I was forwarded to stackfullow.com, pretending to be SO by title, layout, logo, URL pattern, pretty much in every aspect.

However, it's riddled with popups and other nasty stuff I won't even begin to analyse. Can this (probably malicious website) be stopped?

More details: I was searching Google for 'mvc 6 actionlink as button', and the result showed up on 4th place, description as follows: 'Newest 'actionlink' Questions - Stack Overflow'. The actual was www.stackfullow.com/questions/37327040/using-buttons-in-gridmvc.

I'm not sure this question is valid here, because none of the tags seem to apply.

Comment: Report it to [Google](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/)? If there's any actual dangerous content on it and it's on blacklists, browsers should show a big red window when trying to access it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content

Comment: @theB I filled out the form, thanks!

Comment: @Kyll Reported to Google as well, thanks!

Comment: @Mithrandir I can't add this one since I lack the required reputation (bonus 100 does not count)