# How can we prevent users from plagiarizing answers using article spinners?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

Artificial intelligence is becoming more, well, intelligent. AI can be used for good, but it can also be used for bad. Take article spinners for example. While article spinners *used to* produce really crappy and unreadable content, powerful article spinners are now able to completely paraphrase text. Article spinners can be used to do bad things, such as "spinning" a Wikipedia article for a school report.

This also has significance on Stack Overflow. Many questions have multiple answers that say basically the same thing. With article spinners, users can easily run someone else's answer through a spinner and post the result as their own. This isn't straight copy-and-pasting, but this still isn't legit.

How can we prevent users from plagiarizing answers using article spinners?

Comment: What is "article spinning"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: @AdamLear https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_spinning

Comment: Jeff Atwood used to call problems on SO that primarily exist in the OP's imagination "imagineering"

Comment: https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: I blame it on the octopus witch

Comment: Is this you slyly admitting how you keep coming up with Meta questions that have an appropriate structure but nonsensical content?

Comment: I don't think there are measures to prevent people from plagiarizing in general, talking about article spinners is oddly specific. It is an act of moderation after the fact.

Comment: Back in my day, we had to spin our own articles.  But we didn't like it, still.

Answer (score 5):

Let's get a few things straight:

- So long as there is adequate attribution per the CC-by-SA license, **there is no issue** if the material is reposted.
- There are no actual tangible users (on the network) to "deal" with, as reposting content without attribution is a legal matter.

That aside...I'm unaware of any tools that moderators can use to detect plagiarism of Stack Overflow content, but the best people to deal with that is Stack Overflow directly.  [There is a way to report such sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906/1079354), and it should be exercised liberally if you're seeing plagiarism occurring.

Comment: This is not about copying posts to other sites. This is about plagiarizing answers, spinning answers, and posting answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @narawagames I'm not super familiar with this problem.  Do you have some example posts / answers you could link to?