# Another possible Stack Overflow phishing site?

Tags: discussion, phishing

This kind of looks suspicious:
[Stack Fullow?](http://stackfullow.com)
...and while on subject, how and where do you report phishing sites?

[EDIT] It seems that the site redirects the login and sign up links to the original Stack Overflow, but, again, I don't see the purpose of it, and still looks suspicious

Comment: I'm pretty sure for phishing, you use the same process as for [scrapers.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content)

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do).

Comment: same guy has a whole bunch of similar sites: thepirateboys.com etc

Comment: Oh... I see the point, it's filled with pop-up ads :)