# Is stack-overflow.ga related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, copycat-sites, phishing

I entered my credentials at http://stack-overflow.ga/ by accident.

Is this site related to the Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: It looks like an attempt at scraping, not a valid stack exchange page. I'd change my password if I were you whilst we wait for the official answer.

Comment: [Highly relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906/7296893). Of course, Stack Exchange hasn't suddenly hosted a dysfunctional copy on the free .ga domain.

Comment: Yeah if you use this password elsewhere, you should change it. // I've already signaled this site recently (with a bunch of other similar ones). I suppose it doesn't hurt if other people do it too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906/2227743

Comment: Wow, that is full on bad.

Comment: How did you even find that url?

Comment: So... you enter credentials to a page without HTTPS? That's plain carelessness, doesn't matter if Stack Overflow or Google. Amazingly, they couldn't care enough to move the `https://stackexchange.com` links to a spam one