# Why is `www.xszz.org` hosting exact copies of SO questions and answers

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites, scraping

I have seen numerous examples, but below is one example I have just seen today, I am sure there are many more.

[Git: fatal: fsync error on 'sha1 file': Bad file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929881/git-fatal-fsync-error-on-sha1-file-bad-file-descriptor)

https://www.xszz.org/faq-1/question-2018090535252.html

In case xszz removes it, a screenshot is below.

[image: xszz screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The content on SO is under a CC-BY-SA licence so other sites can host that content as well, if they comply to the requirement that they give proper attribution. There is nothing wrong or against the license if the content is used that way.

If no proper attribution is provided the site can be reported to SE as a scraper. See [What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-should-i-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-stack-exchange-sites-for-content) for the correct procedure on that.

Comment: Just to be clear: the site in question is not anywhere close to being compliant with the license (in particular, the attribution requirements), and should be reported.