# My Question and Answers is Plagiarized

Tags: discussion, support

Recent I saw a comment on my answer, it said: "Your answer is Plagiarized". When clicking the link I was shocked, they have been copied questions, answer and tags.

Stackoverflow link: [how to un fork the github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831301/how-to-un-fork-the-github-repository)

Intellipaat link: https://intellipaat.com/community/21779/unfork-github-how-to-unfork-the-github-repository

Even google show their result in the first place
[image]

Comment: They've even actively removed your reference to another stackoverflow Answer :O

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-should-i-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-stack-exchange-sites-for-content

Comment: @Damien I'd go so far as to say that this is a duplicate of [What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-should-i-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-stack-exchange-sites-for-content), this question isn't actually _asking_ anything, and that post provides the guidance on what to do in this case