# What should we do about answers that post from scraper sites?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, attribution

I ran across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63128322/2587435) that got their information from a [scraper site](https://html.developreference.com/article/11481206/What+is+the+difference+between+a+Servlet+filter+and+a+Jersey+filter%3F). I figured it was a scraper site because the answer looked very familiar. Maybe because [it's my answer from a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210283/2587435).

The answerer most likely did not know it was a scraper site and so posted an answer from the site, almost verbatim, and gave attribution to the site.

What should I do in this case about this answer?

Comment: Relevant: [What should I do about a clone service scraping Stack Exchange sites for content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906/11682469)

Comment: Seems like the scraper site itself fails to properly attribute its content. I don't see any links or mentions to Stack Overflow. There is similarly no mention of you or the original question author.

Comment: Yes I understand the site should be reported. My question is more about the answer and what precisely should be done with it. This is the first time I've encountered this, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: My understanding is that if essentially just reposting info from somewhere else then it should be mod-flagged. Merely having a link to the source doesn't excuse it.

Comment: The existence of a scraper site is a red herring in this case. You are the original author of the content, you posted an answer on SO, and someone else copied that answer without attribution. That's plagiarism. We don't allow it. You should raise a moderator flag on the answer, provide us with a link to your original answer, and tell us that it was plagiarized/copied without permission. We will delete it. There is no reason to engage at all with the user, in comments or otherwise. That is just likely to turn acrimonious. Let a moderator handle it; it's what we're here for.