# Is newbedev a copy of Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion

Is it my imagination or is https://newbedev.com/ a copy of Stack Overflow questions?

Comment: They're not following the attribution rules, at least

Comment: Most likely. Please use the "contact us" form to let SO know about as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253906)

Comment: Yea, and the top few links in there are 1:1 copies from SE questions.

Comment: Perhaps also notice that the guidance has changed; Stack Overflow no longer wishes for you to report these sites via "Contact Us".